# Looking for origin/ verification of malicious domain names

Tags: malware, websites, tools, sniffing, domain

My network sniffer for websites has discovered a number of hosting domains in the report which I can not correctly assign to categories. I don't know if there are providers behind these domains that load tags or trackers or if malware/adware simply appeared in the network traffic from the website users.

What I have tried so far:

- Detailed Google research on what these domains are (all without sufficient results).
- Hybrid-analysis.com => The results here don't seem satisfactory either, as I don't think the reports are significant. Maybe someone knows a good alternative to this?

The domain names are all very weird and don't seem to be authentic. These are the domains Im talking about:

1. o104379.ingest.sentry.io
2. 1637314617.rsc.cdn77.org
3. o207331.ingest.sentry.io
4. api.vkanalytics.net
5. piwik.dev.arvm.de
6. tq.96yingxiao.com
7. vorsare.trouplet.com
8. carsapp.club
9. meetcrs.club
10. trymysadoroh.site
11. frgtylik.com
12. 3qkwyj7.x3hn2p.com

As I know what tags should be loaded on the website, these domains make no sense to me and I want to know what they stand for. I hope someone can advise a method to get sufficient information. I would suggest by all those non-sufficient results from google that they may actually be adware/ malware, but I want to be sure about this that they don't come from the website.

Comment: Try checking out a Threat Intelligence feed. I checked these on Threat Connect and found no matches to known public threat systems.

Comment: We can't recommend tools. The potential options might never end. And we can't analyse the domains for you. We can advise on methods and approaches to categorising them.

Comment: *"these domains make no sense to me and I want to know what they stand for"* - Find out their admins and ask them. But on Security SE such questions are **off topic**. I suggest to close it.